# Alignment at the decimal, but centering of numbers without decimal

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment, dcolumn

I have the following issue: I'm exporting regression output from Stata and inputing into my LaTex document. My goal is to write headers and footers in latex and simply input the raw "table-data" with `\input{}`.  I use tabularx and align at the decimal. But I also want to print the number of observations in my table. These are round about 250-1500, they are aligned at the decimal so to speak, but since they have no decimal they throw of the visual effect of decimal alignment. I would rather instead center them in the column. I know this is possible by putting a `\mulitcolumn{}{}{}` environment around it, but this would require manual changes every time I update the table that is created by Stata. I'm looking for a scalable solution. Is it possible to somehow define a columntype that is flexible enough to align numbers between {-1,1} at the decimal, and center numbers without decimals.

Here is an example of my table:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{D..{1.5}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
{\footnotesize
\lipsum[5]}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L{3.8cm} @{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{2}{Y}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}  \\
\midrule
\input{tab}
\midrule
Firm FE & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{X}    \\
Time FE & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{X} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

where the file tab.tex is saved directly from Stata and contains the following code:

```
Variable 1 & 0.012 & -0.542 \\
Variable 2 & 0.523 & 0.235 \\
\midrule
No. of Obs. & 1459 & 255 \\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to do something similar recently, and didn't find a way to solve it from the LaTeX side. From the Stata side it can be done by modifying the output table a bit. Here is the Stata code which uses `esttab`:

```
clear all
set more off
set obs 1000
gen x1 = rnormal()
gen x2 = rnormal()
gen y = 1+2*x1+3*x2+rnormal()
gen z = 1+3*x1+2*x2+rnormal()

eststo clear
eststo: reg y x1 x2
estadd local firm "\multicolumn{1}{c}{X}"
estadd local year "\multicolumn{1}{c}{X}"
estadd local obs "\multicolumn{1}{c}{`e(N)'}"
eststo: reg z x1 x2
estadd local firm "\multicolumn{1}{c}{X}"
estadd local year "\multicolumn{1}{c}{X}"
estadd local obs "\multicolumn{1}{c}{`e(N)'}"
esttab using table.tex, replace b(a3) nonum mtitles("y" "z") ///
       starlevels($^{*}$ .1 $^{**}$ .05  $^{***}$ 0.01) ///
       se label nonotes noobs booktabs align(S) ///
       scalars("obs No. of Obs." "firm Firm FE" "year Year FE")
```

As you can see, instead of reporting just the number of observations it emits all the `\multicolumn` code. Also, it uses the `S` alignment character which assumes usage of `siunitx`. The corresponding LaTeX code can be the following (the key `siunitx` setting is `input-symbols={()}`, without it the standard errors cannot be parsed):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{group-digits=false,parse-numbers=true,input-symbols={()},table-align-text-post=false,
         table-number-alignment=center,table-figures-integer=3,table-figures-decimal=5}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\input{table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And for the reference, I also show the generated `table.tex`:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{y}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{z}\\
\midrule
x1                  &       1.952$^{***}$&       2.971$^{***}$\\
                    &    (0.0318)        &    (0.0314)        \\
\addlinespace
x2                  &       3.013$^{***}$&       1.992$^{***}$\\
                    &    (0.0308)        &    (0.0304)        \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &       1.067$^{***}$&       0.987$^{***}$\\
                    &    (0.0310)        &    (0.0306)        \\
\midrule
No. of Obs.         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{1000}        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{1000}        \\
Firm FE             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{X}        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{X}        \\
Year FE             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{X}        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{X}        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
```

Another idea could be in using some kind of a postprocessor and add the `\multicolumn` stuff after the table is generated.

The result is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `siunitx`. This requires some massage to the table code, but the result is much better.

Entries you want centered in their `S` column are simply entered bracing them.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
}
\toprule
 & {(1)} & {(2)}  \\
\midrule
Variable 1 & 0.012 & -0.542 \\
Variable 2 & 0.523 & 0.235 \\
\midrule
No. of Obs. & {1459} & {255} \\
\midrule
Firm FE & {X}& {X} \\
Time FE & {X}& {X} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I used `twocolum`, hoping you have a two column paper (a three column table as wide as the global text width would be *very* difficult to read).

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much.